# Strange blurry text in HTML (canvas and svg)

Tags: javascript, fonts, blurry

I've got a strange behaviour with a font, the text is blurry following vertical (and horizontal but this is harder to spot) "columns". This is tested on a canvas and on a svg with chrome. The behaviour is almost identical between the two.

Have a look at the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ryderone/m9kpjto3/170

Or look at the snippet below.

As you can see, I have very sharp chars, and very blurry chars depending on where it's printed.

```js
// test with canvas
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var coef = 1; // try to hidpi canvas, increase this to increase the ratio

canvas.width = 300 * coef;
canvas.height = 300 * coef;
document.fonts.onloadingdone = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.font = (13 * coef) + 'px visitor2';

  for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 10 * i * coef + i;
    ctx.fillText(" AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   " + x + "/" + y, x | 0 + 0.5, y | 0 + 0.5);
  }
}

// same test with svg
var svg = document.querySelector('#svg');
for (var j = 1; j < 19; j++) {
  var x = 10;
  var y = 10 * j + j;
  var element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
  element.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x + '');
  element.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y + '');
  element.style.fontFamily = 'visitor2';
  element.style.fontSize = '13px';
  element.style.fill = '#ffffff';
  var txt = document.createTextNode(" AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   " + x + "/" + y);
  element.appendChild(txt);
  svg.appendChild(element);
}
```

```css
#canvas,
#svg {
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: visitor2;
  src: url('https://ryder-one.github.io/hmap/visitor2.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" id="svg"></svg>
```

*Note that the run button above is not working properly for the canvas (left side) since I didn't do the font face loading. But it's working on the jsfiddle if you press run multiple times.*

I don't think this is a subpixel canvas thing since it's happening also on the SVG, with exactly the same behavior; and I don't think this is a device ratio thing neither. I don't think something is wrong with the font because I've seen the exact same font used in a flash project and it's working perfectly.

I've basically checked all SO questions about blurry text on canvas, and HTML in general. I've found some interesting answers but I didn't found any posts describing this exact behaviour.

Does someone has any idea on what can cause this behaviour and how to solve it ?

Thanks !

**EDIT 1 :** [Here is the picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgWZ8.png)

**EDIT 2 :** Please, do not edit the post to make a thumbnail of this picture, since the resize made by SO hide the actual problem. Click on the link to see the picture in full size. Thank you.

**EDIT 3 :** I wasn't clear enough in the original post. This is not a canvas related problem since the same problem occurs also on an SVG. Some of the viewers of the post said they were not able to reproduce the problem with their browser, the canvas and the SVG were both crisp clear. I'm thinking about a chrome related problem or something like that.

Comment: `Note that the run button above is not working properly`  The run button works fine, it's just that you wasn't waiting for the font to load before drawing to the canvas..  I've done a quite update on your snippet to make it work, it's better than having to jump to the fiddle.. :)

Comment: SVG looks perfectly crispy to me on chrome

Comment: To your problem, I'm not sure what problem we are looking at, I'm not seeing any strange blurry text here.  Small fonts, yes, but seems sharp here.  Chrome 73.0.3683.103 on windows.

Comment: Thank you for the loader @Keith.
I edited the post to add a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: You probably want to update that picture, because it's not exactly showing off what you're talking about. I'd recommend showing two images: one base image (without any of the text etc around it, just show the "AAAAA" string as typeset in the two contexts) and then some cropped zooms that clearly show sharp vs. blurry.

Comment: As for why the text might look blurry in the canvas: remember that canvas positions _are not pixel positions_, they're grid locations. So if you draw a 1 px thick line from (0,0) to (100,0), then you're telling the canvas to draw a line _between_ two rows of pixels, and yeah that's going to look blurry. So: if everything looks blurry, step one is a `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5)` before you draw anything.

Comment: I found an interesting post on that matter (TLDR look for the Solution titled section): https://medium.com/wdstack/fixing-html5-2d-canvas-blur-8ebe27db07da

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My previous comment has been deleted, I have no idea why so I will try to be as clear as possible : read the entire post before posting an answer and / or editing the original post please. The solution you gave has already been tested and this is written in the original post.

Comment: @j3ff this is indeed an interesting post, but as stated in my original post : this is not a subpixel problem, neither a canvas problem (happening also on SVG).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, this seems like an odd problem. Like @Keith, to me your SVG look perfectly sharp but I do see the blur on the canvas (using Chrome 74.0.3729.131 on Windows 10)

Comment: Yes I edited the post to add that information. I think it's Chrome or OS related and it has nothing to do with HTML or javascript. When I try chrome or chromium I can see the problem, and when I use firefox, both the canvas and the svg are crisp clear.

Comment: @Ryderone I edited your post and made the image an image _link_ which you should stick with: it lets people see what you mean, and click through if they need to. If the image is "too small to be useful", say that in the post, and then say "I made it a link so you can see it at full size, too" and now you have [a better question](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly the fault of your font.

Its kerning is not correctly set and will make this succession of characters fall on floating coordinates.
At some point, the browser will have to trigger font-smoothing algorithm. Different OS and browsers will use different font-smoothing algorithm by default, and screen with different pixel density will have more or less noticeable artifacts; that's probably why others don't see the same result as yours (I do).

Not much you can do apart complaining to the designer, it may even appear with HTML:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: visitor2;
  src: url('https://ryder-one.github.io/hmap/visitor2.woff') format('woff');
}
#test {
  font: 13px visitor2;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks on my FF on macOs (sub-pixel antialiasing):

[image: screenshot of sub-pixel antialiasing with close-up view]

And here is how it looks on my Chrome (grayscale antialiasing):

[image: screenshot of grayscale antialiasing with close-up view]

---

**For the SVG and HTML**, you could try to disable the antialiasing, though IIIRC **that would work only for Chrome on macOs systems**, by using the non-standard [font-smooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) CSS property to `none`. But doing so, the browser will use a nearest-neighbor like algorithm which will just create a gap in your text:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: visitor2;
  src: url('https://ryder-one.github.io/hmap/visitor2.woff') format('woff');
}
#test {
  font: 13px visitor2;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-smooth: none; /* in case it works one day*/
  -webkit-font-smoothing: none; 
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<br>
</div>
```

And here is how it looks like on my Chrome:

[image: screenshot of same text with no antialiasing]

So yes, there is no blur anymore, but you get a nice gap after 13th character.

---

**For the <canvas>**, the default is transparency antialiasing, which is logic since the browser doesn't know what will be drawn behind.
But there is a little-known feature that allows us to force sub-pixel antialiasing on macOs. By initiating our 2D context with the  `alpha: false` option, most browsers will set the font-smoothing as sub-pixel:

```js
document.fonts.onloadingdone = e => {
  // tell our context it won't have transparency
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {alpha: false});
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.font = (13) + 'px visitor2';
  for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
    var x = 10;
    var y = 10 * i + i;
    ctx.fillText(" AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   " + x + "/" + y, x | 0 + 0.5, y | 0 + 0.5);
  }
  
  // draw close-up
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, -70, 70, canvas.width * 5, canvas.height * 5);
};
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: visitor2;
  src: url('https://ryder-one.github.io/hmap/visitor2.woff') format('woff');
}
#canvas {
  font: 13px visitor2; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="200"></canvas>
```

So now at least, you have the possibility to choose between both antialising methods.

Comment: Wow very nice answer thanks. For many reasons I choosed SVG over canvas, so I think I'm stuck with the blur if I keep this font.